# Cannot Click Home Button On Navigation Bar In Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I click a home button on navigation bar in my custom wordpress theme cannot give any response like open the home page. Please check [my own theme](http://dev.galerigadget.com/) on this link to further info. Its home button screenshot below:

[image: home button]

**Here css style for navigation bar:**

```
 .navbar-header {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I have been trying to fix it but still not luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ist that the div "navbar-collapse" is full width and sitting on top of the button. Therefore when you're trying to click the button you actually click "navbar-collapse".

For a quick fix you could:

- give "navbar-collapse" a width and set it to "margin: 0 auto;". It will then no longer overlay your button.

or

- increase the z-index of "navbar-header" --> z-index 21 will do in your case

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.navbar-header {
  /* your own styles */
  z-index:9999;
}
```

The `li` in `.collapse .navbar-collapse` lays over your navbar. You are clicking that piece in stead of your header. With `z-index` you bring the header back to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Already `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">` has z-index:20.
So it overlay your main nav-bar.

Use the below css

```
.navbar-header {
    z-index: 21;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you css .. because its width is 100% and its overlapping the Home Button.. `Line no 246 in style.css`

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;}
```